Extracting Exact p-values from the "did" Package Output in R
I'm working on a Difference-in-Differences (DiD) analysis with multiple periods and groups using the did package in R. The package provides significance information based on 95% confidence intervals (CIs) in its output. However, it only indicates whether the p-value is above or below 0.05, and does not provide the exact p-value or degrees of freedom.
Here is the basic output from the did package for my Average Treatment Effect on the Treated (ATT) estimation:
Example output of group specific effects
I'm primarily interested in determining if the ATT is significantly different from zero, which involves a basic two-sided hypothesis test:

Null Hypothesis (H0): ATT = 0
Alternative Hypothesis (H1): ATT ≠ 0

While the confidence intervals help to some extent, I would like to obtain the exact p-value for a more precise hypothesis test. If there’s a way to extract the exact p-value or the degrees of freedom from the did package output, I can proceed with my analysis accordingly.
How do I get these details from the did package? Since the data is strictly confidential, I can neither provide the data nor the exact code. But one can replicate some thing similar following code:
library(did)
data("mpdta")
out <- att_gt(
  yname = "lemp",
  gname = "first.treat",
  idname = "countyreal",
  tname = "year",
  xformla = ~ 1,
  data = mpdta,
  est_method = "reg"
)

group_effects <- aggte(out, type = "group")
summary(group_effects)


If you print out there's a P-value for pre-test of parallel trends assumption printed at the end. Try out$Wpval. It seems to be it.

Dear Rui, thank you for your comment. In my understanding the wpval is  the value of the test  that tests whether the common trends assumption holds across the pre-treatment period. So it evaluates if the trends in outcomes for treated and control groups were parallel before treatment was introduced, However this is not what i need. I need he statistical significance of the estimated treatment effects or average treatment effects on the treated (ATT) at specific points in time or across different groups, so the pvalue for each estimate.

Why not divide the estimate by the standard error to get a z score? The z score will be the number of standard errors the estimate is away from 0. The two-tailed p value for a given z will be 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(z)))

Just FYI if you cannot provide the code or the data then Stack Overflow is not the appropriate place to ask. Hire a consultant and have them sign an NDA. Debugging questions on this site require that you be able to provide the code and data needed to reproduce the exact problem, not pseudo code or summarizing.

Following Alan Cameron's suggestion in comment, this function computes z-scores and their p-values for a given critical alpha.
p_value <- function(x, alpha = 0.05) {
  z <- x[["att"]]/x[["se"]]
  qq <- qnorm(1 - alpha/2)
  p.value <- qq * (1 - pnorm(abs(z)))
  p.value
  # data.frame(group = x[["group"]], t = x[["t"]], p.value)
}

p_value(out)
#>  [1] 0.6542655553 0.0398899061 0.0004680037 0.0042040307 0.7509016443
#>  [6] 0.8735410981 0.7822418283 0.0353974488 0.0460965697 0.8513119469
#> [11] 0.0752458753 0.1452859311

Created on 2024-08-27 with reprex v2.1.0

Dear Allen and Dear Rui, thanks a lot for you answers. I did not think about the CLT and the z-value. No need for DoF in this case. Actually the alpha in the function is not necessary but you answer still helped out of my misery. All the best Jonah
